# Ecommerce - responsive or mobile site?

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, e-commerce

Been wondering lately about responsive vs mobile site, especially for ecommerce. I have a rather big project coming up and it seems like it will be a relatively heavy one (in terms of templates and functionality). So immediate thought is to do a mobile site to cut on certain functionality that may be performance heavy but not that required. But does this make sense these days? Would there still be advantage of going mobile with ecommerce, or perhaps should just do a responsive?

Comment: Do you understand that a responsive site IS a mobile site? I am not sure if you completely understand the definition of the term "responsive" based on your question - just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Sorry, yeah I do understand this. Perhaps used wrong wording. I meant a separate site just for mobile devices as opposed to a responsive one

Comment: This is not really a programming question then, but a business decision. I do not believe it is appropriate for this site.

Comment: It kinda is programming question. Unless I'm totally mistaken about the concept. I may not be a master in responsive design nor development, but when you do a responsive template you are not sorting out performance problem as all of that happens server side. If you want to get rid of certain features on a mobile view, you can hide it on the frontend, but they still get processed server side. Perhaps this is not something considered an issue these days anymore?

Answer (score 1):

There are advantages and disadvantages of doing a mobile site and a responsive website. I've recently went through this decision in my work as well. The points below are the main points I looked at when updating my website.

Mobile:
- Specific site created for mobile devices 
- New domain name needed for the mobile site
- This may need to be updated as new phones are developed or new screen sizes are developed.

Responsive: 
- Site is adjusted based on the screen size of the users device
- Lots of up-front coding needed
- No specific mobile domain needed.
- Currently no new code needed for new device sizes.

Although there was a lot of back end work (and I'll be honest there was a lot of back end work!). I think choosing responsive was right for my situation.

If you plan to use the website for a long period of time and you have the resources and time to devote to a responsive design I believe it's worth it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most compelling reasons for making a responsive e-commerce website is that Google recommend it!

Bear in mind Google's market share and that most of your [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) effort will be for Google. The following configuration is detailed by [Google](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/recommendations-for-building-smartphone.html), the highlight is their own:

> Sites that use responsive web design, i.e. sites that serve all
>   devices on the same set of URLs, with each URL serving the same HTML
>   to all devices and using just CSS to change how the page is rendered
>   on the device. **This is Google’s recommended configuration**.

Moreover, with frameworks like Bootstrap responsive websites are relatively straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

committing to a separate mobile website is a commitment to its ongoing maintenance -- so there has to be the budget/resources to do that.

another alternative is to use a front end framework like (twitter) bootstrap 3 that allows the website to be 'mobile first'. this was the breaking change between bootstrap 2 and bootstrap 3 -- bootstrap 3 looks for mobile devices first to speed up the rendering.

http://getbootstrap.com

the code needed for bootstrap 3 is relatively easy to implement -- but it is a commitment because all of your templates and forms and layout all have to be done with its code.

i am using bootstrap 3 for e-commerce and its great. a huge advantage of using bootstrap 3 is that as new phones etc come out, they are testing etc. some people complain that bootstrap sites look the same -- but for e-commerce -- having the interface look and feel 'familiar' for customers is good for sales.